# Branching a subdirectory while keeping commits from other directories

Tags: git, svn

I currently have a single pre-existing Git repo for a client/server solution that contains three subdirectories for 3 sub-projects:

```
/client  - An Angular2 SPA application (client-side TypeScript)
/dtos    - Language-agnostic web-service DTO (data contract) definitions written in T4
    /client - T4-generated TypeScript typings *.d.ts files
    /server - T4-generated C# DTO classes
/server  - The web-service
```

So far this is all in a single `master` branch, with appropriate temporary `dev/` branches that are merged when their work is complete:

```
o--o--o--o - master
 \   /
  o-o      - dev/foo
```

We need to do some A/B (or rather, A/B/C/D) testing on radically different UX options in the Angular2 project - I would like to branch-off for each UX option, to generate different builds we can test, then after our UX research is done we merge that specific branch back into `master` for the remainder of the project:

```
o             - master
 \
  o--o--o---o - ux/red-background
   \
    o--o----o - ux/new-sidebar
        \
         o--o - ux/new-sidebar-and-banner
```

However I only want to branch the `/Client` directory off - so the `/DTOs` and `/Server` directories always contain the latest code.

In SVN and TFS this is easily doable because branches can be made from subdirectories, not just the entire repository (as they are with git), so if this were an SVN project then I would do something like this:

```
cd trunk  # this is the solution root with the client, dtos and server directories
svn copy ^/trunk/client ^/branches/red-background
svn copy ^/branches/red-background ^/branches/new-sidebar
# then after some commits to 'new-sidebar'...
svn copy ^/branches/new-sidebar ^/branches/new-sidebar-and-banner
```

Then to build the solution with each different branch of `/client` we modify the symlink:

```
cd trunk
# to 'checkout' the red-background version prior to building:
ln -s branches/red-background client
# or the new-sidebar version:
ln -s branches/new-sidebar client
```

The main advantage of this approach is that commits can continue to be made to the `/dtos` and `/server` directories without affecting `client` at all - regardless of whatever branch of `client` is being worked-in.

Whereas with git, a branch is a separate timeline entirely, so this scenario becomes impossible.

I understand that to get the result I want, I would still need to create different branches for each version to test or build, but changes to `/dtos` or `/server` would still need to happen in `master` (just like in `trunk` in SVN) but after every commit everyone working on the different `client` branches would need to `rebase` or `merge` from `master`, and that has the potential to get really ugly (especially if individual people `rebase` from multiple commits to `/server` choosing their own rebase points - they might end up with identical codebases but different commit hashes).

What's the solution?

(Another solution is to move `client` to its own git repo - then merging it back into the solution repo when it's all done - I'm not opposed to this but let's pretend that we've hit our maximum repo count in our organizational GitHub account)

Comment: ... this is a non issue if folks working on a feature branch pull the latest code every morning. `git pull --rebase origin develop` done.

Comment: @RubberDuck The problem with rebasing is that it rewrites history and has to be done for each development and feature branch, which is hardly ideal.

Comment: A) It just straightens out history in this context. No big deal. B) It takes about 10 seconds. Again, not a big deal. Don't over complicate a simple thing.

Comment: I'm going to put this bluntly. You're imagining a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way is to move client to its own repository and make it a submodule of the super project. But if you do not want to create a new repository you can try one of these solutions.

## Multiple directories in one branch

If you are able to configure your project to use directory /client_A instead of /client then you can clone the directory /client to multiple directories

- /client_A
- /client_B
- /client_C

and do separate development in each of these directories. Up to this point it is enough to use only master branch.
Later when you decide to "merge" directory /client_A to directory /client create a branch named e.g. branch_A. In this branch replace the content of directory /client with content of directory /client_A, delete directory /client_A and commit this state. Then merge branch_A to master and solve conflicts if any.
Do the same with directories /client_B and /client_C if you want to "merge" them with directory /client. You can choose different times for "merging" directories /client_A, /client_B and /client_C into directory /client.

## Multiple branches without cloning directories

Choose a suitable start time and make as many branches from master as you want

- branch_A
- branch_B
- branch_C

From this start time use strictly

- master for changes in directories other than /client (/dtos and /server)
- branch_A, branch_B, branch_C for changes in /client directory

Use branch_A, branch_B, branch_C for building different versions of your project. Merge master branch into these branches before building. Avoid merging these branches into master branch (the opposite direction).
Later you can merge e.g. branch_A into master. But after doing this you can't merge master into branch_B or branch_C. This means that you need to choose suitable end time and merge all branches branch_A, branch_B, branch_C into master at this time.

Comment: I realise another option is to use Git's ability to checkout a subdirectory to a separate tree root - this technique could be combined with your first "Multiple directories in one branch" approach and with symlinks - though it has the problem of not keeping coherent history (though it would merge painlessly provided each commit only touches a single feature directory)

Comment: Or just do trunk based development - place all three directories side by side in the master branch, and use configuration to choose which one is used at run time. When a decision is made to keep one and get rid of the others just commit the deletion and merge that to master.

Comment: Optionally, rebase the dev branches onto master when nee commits come in on master (but only if they are non-public)